# Gateway / Router Detection with Bash: Functions and Variables.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, admin

I'm drafting / still brainstorming / a `bash` shell script. The aim of which, is to; help the user to:

- *Interface with various **CLI tools***.
- *Perform various **administrative tasks.***

It might, eventually, evolve into a bit of a personalized framework.

---

A particular requirement that it has:

- It should be able to *detect the **IP address*** *of the **gateway / router*** *on the **current LAN***.
- I've come up with `route -n |awk '/UG/{print $2}';` to ***echo*** the ***corresponding IP*** *to **stdout***.

Should I use that *input* as a `function(){}`, its *output* as a `$variable`, or *both*??

---

Comment: Surely that depends on what *specific* behavior you want.  Do be aware that `bash` functions do not have a return value in the same sense that functions in most programming languages do (they have an exit status instead), and that arguments are effectively passed by value.

Comment: I just want to be able to, quickly and easily, pass the IP address, to other networking utilities, and so on. (Like; `nmap`, `netstat`, `iptables`, etc. (for instance.)).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, defining a function like:

```bash
gateway() {
    route -n | awk '/UG/{print $2}';
}
```

...would permit you to:

- Initialize as many variables as you like

  ```
  gw=$(gateway)
  echo $gw
  ```
- Easily handle network reconfigurations which can occur while roaming between several Wifi network

Comment: My thought's exactly. If you check the markup for this question, you can see I tried to provide my own ideas.